# 4 side by side pictures in poster latex

Tags: graphics, minipage, baposter

I look for an example to put 4 pictures side by side in the case of a poster with `baposter` package. thanks

Comment: It would be great if you could add a fully compilable (minimum working) example to your post.

Comment: Please show as the code, with which you are trying to achieve that. We don't want to write all. There are many posts on this side describing the use of the package `subcaption` or others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\includegraphics{a}\includegraphics{b}\includegraphics{c}\includegraphics{d}
```

Will put 4 images side by side in any LaTeX class.